# Finding expected result from a betting line

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

If I have have a betting line at a value of 800 receiving yards for a NFL player that has implied probabilities of 50% for the over and 50% for the under, the expected receiving yards is 800 for these bets.

I am unsure on what the expected receiving yards for a line with odds that aren't 50/50

For example: Betting line of 1000 receiving yards for a player with a 45% over, and a 55% under.

My gut says to multiply the receiving yards by .95 since its 5% away and the expected value of these bettors is 950 yards.

Or to multiply it by .9 (.45 * 2). But I am completely void of trying to find any logic behind these.

Comment: "...the expected receiving yards is 800 for these bets." This is wrong: you are confusing **mean** (i.e. average value) with **median** (i.e. point at which $50$% of the distribution is below and $50$% of the distribution is above).

Comment: "...For example: Betting line of 1000 receiving yards for a player with a 45% over, and a 55% under."  If you consult a distribution chart, and assume that $800$ is the median, you would then conclude that the chance of the yardage being between $800$ and $1000$ is $5$%.  Hence, the ratio of $(50 + 5)$% versus $(50 - 5)$%.

Comment: It seems to me that it is a good thing that you are "...completely void of trying to find any logic behind these."  Trying to connect mean with median, or to use the median to predict the point at which (for example) $(55)$% of the distribution is below the point can be very tricky, and may require assumptions that don't hold with a specific set of data.

Comment: This is the boundary where I am out of my depth, never having studied statistics.  However, I do know that it is generally not a good idea to try to re-invent the wheel, for math below the post-graduate level.  I suggest finding the *right* statistics book for you, and opening it to page 1.

Comment: By the way: +1 for your question, which shows imagination, and reasonably nice work shown.